# How can I grant GET_ACCOUNTS permission for Android N?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, authentication, permissions

I'm developing a flutter app which authenticates with Microsoft Azure.
On Android N the application is unable to authenticate. It starts the authentication process but it's aborted in the middle.

I checked the system logs and found this log message

[image: Logs screenshot]

I'm facing this issue only on Android N. It's working fine on Android versions less than 6 and Android 8 and 9

I read the documentation and found that GET_ACCOUNTS permission is no longer required for Android 6 and higher and I only need to grant READ_CONTACTS permission to the application

I granted all the permissions but still not working

[image: Granted Permissions from Mainfest]

I'm also prompting the user to grant permission in runtime with permission_handler library and users are prompted successfully and even when Access is granted, I still get the same issue

I'm using the following code to prompt the user when he tries to login

`if (await _requestPermission(Permission.contacts)) {}`

_requestPermission function is as following

```
 Future<bool> _requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
    if (await permission.isGranted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      var result = await permission.request();
      if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Appreciate any assistance as I'm stuck. Thanks.